# Как объединить регулярные выражения python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, qregularexpression

Требуется найти номер телефона в тексте.
Возможно ли найти универсальное регулярное выражение, чтобы номер находился как вначале текста, так и в середине и в конце?
Например следующее выражение находит номер только в середине текста:

```
import re

text = '''sometext +79959999999 sometext'''
re.findall(r'[\S|\s](\+\d{11})[\S|\s]', text)
```

Следующее регулярное выражение находит только вначале:

```
text = '''+79959999999 sometext'''
re.findall(r'^(\+\d{11})[\S|\s]', text)
```

Ну и соответственно только в конце строки или текста:

```
text = '''sometext +79959999999'''
re.findall(r'[\S|\s](\+\d{11})$', text)
```

При этом ещё нужно учесть, что телефон может быть одновременно вначале и в конце текста (то есть весь текст это номер):

```
text = '''+79959999999'''
re.findall(r'^(\+\d{11})$', text)
```

Выражение вида:

```
re.findall(r'[^|\S|\s](\+\d{11})[$|\S|\s]', text)
```

Почему-то не работает

Вариант типа оставить только

```
re.findall(r'(\+\d{11})', text)
```

не подходит, так как если номер длиной больше 11 цифр, то он будет его обрезать, а нужны именно 11-значные.

Comment: r'\b(\+\d{11}\b)'

Comment: Так не работает.

Comment: `\+\d{11}(?!\d)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VvTquk/1

Comment: @splash58 Интересно всё-таки, почему в начале `\b` не работает как надо )

Comment: @CrazyElf потому что + не является "элементом слова" - не входит в \w

Comment: В итоге ничего не подходит мне. Если телефон вида "(999)9999999", то нужно, чтобы вначале была не цифра, чтобы находил именно этот телефон, но при этом номер может быть вначале строки. 
[^\d]\([\d]{3}\)[\d]{7} - так находит, но только если номер не вначале строки

Comment: грубо, наверное, так: re.findall(r'(^|\b|\s)(\+7\d{10})($|\b|\s)', text, re.M) Если интересуют номера в РФ, то я бы предусмотрел и начальную 8 вместо +7, Хотя вообще-то телефон РФ не может быть "любого вида" после +7, например с +7 так же будут начинаться номера... Казахстана, с диапозонами 6хх и 7хх. Если, конечно, это имеет значение для задачи. См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Ну а если начинаем учитывать еще и скобки, пробелы, тире и прочее.... то куда-то в эту сторону: (^|\b|\s)((\+7|8)? ?\(?\d{3}\)? ?\d{3}(-| )?\d{2}(-| )?\d{2})($|\b|\s) - но потом из найденного удалять все кроме цифр и начального "+" (если есть) и приводить к одному виду